# How to retrieve data from database to CheckedListBox and set the items as checked?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, foreach, checkedlistbox

I am new in WPF. I am trying to load the values from database to fill in `CheckedListBox`. Based on a condition, some items must be set to checked while loading in checkedlistbox.
How to do this? I have tried the code below, items are loaded in `CheckedListBox`, but are not checked.
Below is values loaded to checked listbox

```
    public void fillcheck()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        con.Open();
        string comboquery = "SELECT [Machine] FROM Department Where active='True'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(comboquery, con);
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string fil1 = rdr.GetString(0);
            Checkedlistbox1.Items.Add(fil1);
        }
        rdr.Close();

     }




    int departmentID=60//for just refer
   Object[] jobs = CheckedlistBox1.Items.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
   foreach (Object obj in jobs)
   {
    string query = "SELECT [Machine] FROM Department Where ID='" + departmentID+ "'";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
  SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while(rdr.Read())
   {
    string mac = rdr.GetString(0);//Here i get two values(XRAY,CT)but finally shown CT only be checked,so how to do both checked
    if (mac == obj.ToString())
    {
      int indexx = CheckedlistBox1.Items.IndexOf(mac);
      if (indexx >= 0)
      {
        CheckedlistBox1.SetItemChecked(indexx, true);
       }
    }
  }
  rdr.Close();
 }
```

Comment: probably you want to iterate all items in chlstBox.Items rather than chlstBox.CheckedIndices?

Comment: yes,the values are loaded in checkedlistbox,but i cant check based on my condition am mentioned above

Comment: You should have used code-  foreach (int indexChecked in chlstBox.Items) instead of foreach (int indexChecked in chlstBox.CheckedIndices). At start you have 0 selected items.

Answer (score 2):

You need to transfer your SqlDataReader `rdr` content to a `DataTable`. That will help you get a DataTable object containing multiple rows like you have mentioned.

Now for the next step, you can apply a `foreach` on that `DataTable` object to iterate over all its rows like this :

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   if(yourCondition)
   {
      //set isChecked = true for the checkbox.
   }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

Try modifying your `while` loop like this :

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
   string mac = rdr.GetString(0);
   ListItem li = new ListItem();
   li.Value = "yourBindedValue";// some value from database column
   li.Text = "yourBindedText";// use mac if its text.
   int index = Checkedlistbox1.Items.IndexOf(li);
   if (index >= 0)
   {
      Checkedlistbox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
   }
}
```

I have tested this and it works. You just have to pass the `Text` and `Value` of the CheckBoxListItem that you are trying to find in the `li` object and you can get the index if it exists. Make sure you pass **both** the attributes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77612/discussion-on-answer-by-harveyspecter-how-to-retrieve-data-from-database-to-chec).

Answer (score 0):

You should have used code-

```
foreach (int indexChecked in chlstBox.Items)
```

instead of

```
foreach (int indexChecked in chlstBox.CheckedIndices)
```

At start you have 0 selected items and thats why your outer for loop is not working..

EDIT-

Basic Logic is also incorrect.
You should loop through dataset, find the string in checkboxlist and then check it. So, outer foreach loop is not required. Also, make sure that you are using correct checkboxlist variable. In for loop you are using **chlstBox**
and while searching you are using **Checkedlistbox1** ....

Comment: foreach (int indexChecked in chlstBox.Items),this is get values,but it cannot be cheked,it always shows  error "List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change."

Comment: Please see my edit. You do not need outer foreach loop.

Comment: First of all , show complete code. Show code for fillcheckedlist too. Also, HarveySpecter solution should work.